# Change value in views before rendering it at html page

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a `listview` in my Django's project like:

```py
class KaoiroView(ListView):
    template_name = 'main/show-kaoiro.html'
    queryset = Kaoiro.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'kaoiro'
    paginate_by = 10
```

where `Kaoiro` has one column called

```
checkTime = models.BigIntegerField()
```

in `models.py`.

this `checkTime` is an `unixtime` like one big number.

I would like to convert this time when user `get` above page from my `views.py`, but because I'm using a `listview` I don't know how to access this data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a new property in your model class such as :

this property is called derived property you can use any formula or code here to calculate new value.

```py
class kaoiro(models.Model):
...
...
checkTime = models.BigIntegerField()

@property
def normal_time(self):
    ct = self.checkTime 
    ## do something with ct
    return ct
```

you can use `normal_time` as any other property of your class.

Comment: instead of ```checkTime``` use ```normal_time``` now.